# Wordpress, HTACCESS - redirect single page if iPhone or Safari

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I know almost nothing so there may be the problem! But I've tried snippets fro 20 different answers to try and get this and no joy. I have a form on one page which will not work on iPhone or Safari. So I have a second form which will. I need to redirect a single page (https://website.co.uk/normal-page/) to another page (/mobilepage/) only if the browser is Safari, or the device an iPhone.
Here's one effort:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|safari" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/normal-page/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/mobilepage/ [NC,R=301]`

Which stops any access to the page at all - which was a great improvement on no effect. I'm sure it's simple but I can't get it to work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work for three reasons. First of all, your 2nd `RewriteCond` will only work with `/normal-page/`. So if the trailing slash isn't there, it will not pick up the URL. Using `/normal-page` fixes this and works with and without the trailing slash.

The biggest issue was with your `rewriterule`. Your were basically trying to rewrite the URL to: `http://example.com/example.com/mobilepage/` which is obviously breaking your page.

You also shouldn't need the `""` around your first Condition.

Use these rules instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|safari [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/normal-page [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobilepage/ [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this. Also, keep in mind that `R=301` is a permanent redirect, I advise you change this to `R=302` while testing, this is a temporary redirect.

Comment: Did this help you ?

Comment: This did fix it - sorry, thought I'd posted as much but somehow not. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the right place to post this. Eventually I found the HTACCESS route didn't work. Different OS/Browser combos seemed to arbitrarily ignore or apply the rules when they shouldn't. So I went for Javascript. Less robust, as a user may have it disabled, but I'm not clever enough to find anything better.

Since I found this whole process hard to find answers for I thought I'd post my solution up here - but with the caveat that I'm very much an amateur poking about - there my be better ways and better code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var FormSafe = 1;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows")!== -1) FormSafe=2;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")!== -1) FormSafe=3;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("OPR")!== -1) FormSafe=4;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android")!== -1) FormSafe=5;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("BlackBerry")!== -1) FormSafe=6;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!== -1) FormSafe=7;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone")!== -1) FormSafe=1;
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad")!== -1) FormSafe=1;

if ( FormSafe === 1 ) { 
            jQuery("#iphoneform").show(); } else
        { jQuery("#normalform").show(); }
});
</script>
```

I used 1-7 just to bug test by seeing the results. It could just be ==1 for good, 0 for bad for all others. But 1-7 means you could show different div for each browser.

Then it simply shows or hides the element with a form which works for whichever browser/OS combo.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Just for interest. The code ASSUMES Safari (==1) - because the user agent for MANY different browsers contains Safari (very helpful!) - which is why, despite being correct Joe's answer didn't work. So I had to assume Safari, and then 'correct' if it said Chrome etc.